# Use the factor theorem to find all real zeros for the given polynomial function and one factor: $2x^3+5x^2-12x-30$ and factor $2x+5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find all the zeros of  $2x^3+5x^2-12x-30$ given one factor $2x+5$.

The answers are $\frac{-5}{2}$, $\pm\sqrt{6}$.

At this stage in my textbook I have been using synthetic division.

To use $2x+5$ as a factor in synthetic division I want a single leading x in that term so split into $2(x+\frac{5}{2})$

Then:
$\frac{-5}{2}|2 [space] 5[space]-12[space]-30$ # not sure of the markup here so have used [space] for spaces

This results in a remainder of 30 whereas I expected 0.

Photo since I don't know how to write synthetic division with markup (sorry for the head tilt too):
[image]

I expected a remainder of 0 if $\frac{-5}{2}$ really is a zero of $2x^3+5x^2-12x-30$. Presumably my working is wrong. Since I cannot get past this step I will not ask about the $\pm\sqrt{6}$ yet.

How is $\frac{-5}{2}$ a factor of $2x^3+5x^2-12x-30$ if $\frac{-5}{2}$ is not a zero?

Comment: $2(-5/2)^3+5(-5/2)^2-12(-5/2)-30=0$

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not $-2/5$ is a factor, but $2x+5$ is a factor of your polynomial, since we have
$$
2x^3+5x^2-12x-30=(x^2 - 6)(2x + 5).
$$
So we have that $-\frac{2}{5}$ is a *root*, as well
as $\pm \sqrt{6}$. So your polynomial division should give $x^2-6$.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between factors and roots, which are closely connected concepts due to the Factor Theorem, but are *distinct* nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm struggling to follow along 100%. Are you suggesting I should not have attempted synthetic division here and instead used regular polynomial long division? I cannot see how to arrive at $x^2-6$

Comment: Yes, you are right. With [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) you are finished quickly, see the wikipedia examples.

Comment: @DougFir You can also use inspection, as I have outlined in my answer, but if you have just started out learning polynomial division, then I'd recommend sticking with that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=2x^{3}+5x^{2}-12x-30$ then we have $f(-\frac{5}{2})=0$ so by the factor theorem $(x+\frac{5}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(2x+5)$ is a factor of the polynomial $f(x)$.

Indeed we have $f(x)=2x^{3}+5x^{2}-12x-30=(x+\frac{5}{2})(2x^{2}-12)=\frac{1}{2}(2x+5)(2x^{2}-12)=(2x+5)(x^{2}-6).$

So the roots of the polynomial $f(x)$ are $-\frac{5}{2}$ and $\pm\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* for a fact that $2x+5$ is a factor then you can also use another technique: inspection. This is when you factorise the polynomial as you would a quadratic. We know that

$$
2x^3+5x^2-12x-30=(2x+5)(Ax^2+Bx+C)
$$

> Here is my thought process as I work out this factorisation: $A$ must
> be $1$ to get the $2x^3$ term; $1x^2$ is also being multiplied by $5$,
> and so the quadratic terms also work out; this means that $B=0$; and
> finally, $C=-6$ to make the linear and constant terms work out.

With practise, this method is faster than polynomial long division (which I what I assume you are doing right now). However, I would recommend having a firm understanding of polynomial division before you try it out. Then all we have to do is factorise $x^2-6$.

Hint:

> Difference of two squares!

Comment: Thanks Joe! Noted RE inspection. I'm working through an online textbook just now and have not yet encountered this method but look forwards to it